# Remove slug from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

This has been asked many times but each solution I've tried doesn't work for me - I'm trying to remove the slug of a custom post type. I've tried setting

```
 'with_front' => false,
```

but this also doesn't work for me. [With this suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls#answer-204210), it removes the slug in the permalink within the admin area (in my case 'locations') but then visiting the new link I get a 404. I've tried flushing permalinks and this doesn't help. However, I can still access the post by visiting /locations/post-name.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
function remove_custom_post_type_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    $post_link = str_replace( '/locations/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'remove_custom_post_type_slug', 10, 3 );
```

[See Reference](http://www.boopathirajan.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-url/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm still getting the same issue with that code. I've flushed permalinks and still getting 404s without /locations/ but can navigate to /locations/post-name